# Go MySql driver doesn't set time correctly

Tags: mysql, go

I have been developing a micro service that interact mysql for a while in golang, and i love this talented language. Anyway have a problem and do not know where is the problem, in my code, in mysql driver else in mysql. So my machine timezone utc+3, i am sharing some result may be it helps

```
//created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
mysql> select now();
"2016-11-07 22:43:02", //that is correct.
```

in go

```
fmt.PrintLn(time.Now().Local())
"2016-11-07 22:51:02" //that is correct too
```

But when i added the entity into db, mysql workbench shows me wrong datetime.

```
"2016-11-07 19:51:02" //
```

Go code:

```
func (this *AppLogHandler) addLog(_log *AppLog) (int64, error){
    fmt.Println("addLog")
    db:= this.Context.DB
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT tbl_logs SET user_id=?,ip_proxy=?, ip_original=?, end_point=?, http_method=?, message=?, status=?, created_date=?")
    if(err != nil){
        log.Println(err)
        return -1, err
    }
    defer stmt.Close()
    res, err := stmt.Exec(&_log.UserID, &_log.IPProxy, &_log.IPOriginal, &_log.Endpoint, &_log.HttpMethod, &_log.Message, &_log.Status, &_log.CreatedDate)
    if(err != nil){
        log.Println(err)
        return -1, err
    }
    return res.LastInsertId()
}

/// some code here
    app_log := AppLog{}
    app_log.IPProxy = r.RemoteAddr
    app_log.IPOriginal = r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")
    app_log.CreatedDate = time.Now().Local()
    app_log.UserID = user_id
    app_log.Endpoint = r.URL.Path
    app_log.HttpMethod = r.Method
    fmt.Println(app_log.CreatedDate)
    return this.addLog(&app_log)
```

So guys i need your helps. I couldn't solve the problem for hours.

```
mysql=>  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
go => 1.7
mysql driver => 1.2, https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/
```

Comment: Are you running this all on the same machine?  You can get different results if running on machines in different time zones or if one is out of sync with its NTP server.

Comment: Yes, on same machine

Comment: The driver might be passing that in as a string and then parsing it into a time.Time constructor, which would convert it to UTC.  Although time.Time#Local() returns a time.Time. Hmmm

Comment: Probably that will be the reason.

Comment: What's the aversion to UTC?  Generally speaking, UTC is best practice, as it gives you a single source of truth.

Comment: Upps, you'r right! Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mysql driver has a [configuration parameter for the default time zone](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/1fbca2aabb09915d4f1006d01b271ad7778eec4f/dsn.go#L43), which you can set to `time.Local` (the default is `time.UTC`). When you are saving the value, it first [converts the time stamp to the UTC time zone](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/ce924a41eea897745442daaa1739089b0f3f561d/packets.go#L1047) and then sends it off to the database.

As has been already stated in the comments, a much more robust approach would be to accept the default `Loc`, and standardize on UTC in the database. This greatly simplifies anything having to do with date math further down the line, and doesn't make assumptions about the time zone of the person viewing the data if you just convert it from UTC to local when displaying the value.